# Facebook integration with android app without appId?

Tags: android, facebook

hi i want to inegrate facebook to my android application but i do not have appId.
so can it possible in android to call Facebook object without appId?
when i try this it gives me error.in iphone it working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Buddy Its not possible.
You need to use a Facebook App Id to integrate The Facebook in Android.

You can register your Facebook Test Application and See the Tutorial from Facebook here,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a appId. Is there any reason why you dont? Facebook allows you to do this

Comment: coder_For_Life22 thank you for reply.my client does not create any application on facebook and its working fine in iphone without appid so why this is not allowd in android?

Comment: @Megha whenever you login to Facebook..that will ask you first time to allow permission to "blablabla" application to use your fb account to post and do all things..if you want to try in iphone just login with the account that u havent used yet and they will ask to allow permission after login screen..THATS WHERE THE APP ID is REQUIRED it may be possible that iphone developer gone smarter and used their TEST APP ID for fb login. also you can check from iphone and make some post to ur account..and in account you will find bellow the update will be writter "0 MINS AGO VIA BLABLABLA APP"

Comment: Exactly...You need that to get permission for your app to access a clients information